# Which verb would be appropriate for the action of pulling the bolt of a bolt action rifle?

Tags: word-request

Is there a specific verb that denotes the action of pulling the bolt of a [bolt-action](https://en.wikipedia.org/Bolt_action) firearm to load the cartridge?

My searches so far not yielded in any positive result.

Comment: Do you mean the sequence of actions 1. Unlock the bolt and pull it back 2. Insert a cartridge or allow one to feed from a magazine 3. Push forward and lock the bolt? This is called _cocking_ the rifle.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Are all the three collectively called `cocking` or just the (3)?

Comment: Technically, 'cocking' a weapon means to make the firing pin ready and able to strike the firing cap on the cartridge, if the trigger is pulled with the safety catch off. Informally some people use the expression for all three steps I mentioned above. I was trained on the No.4 Lee-Enfield rifle, where the firing pin is cocked by the action of closing the bolt. Some other rifles, notably the Mauser 98k, cock the firing pin by opening the bolt.

Comment: In all the bolt-action rifles I have used, **pulling** the bolt back opens the breech, ejecting any round present, and it is **pushing** the bolt forward which loads a round, whether the round was fed from a magazine or inserted by hand.

Comment: Yes, *cocking* is the word then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a weapon such as a rifle, pistol, machine-gun, etc, ready to fire is called **'cocking'**. Technically, 'cocking' a weapon means to make the firing pin ready and able to strike the firing cap on the cartridge, if the trigger is pulled with the safety catch off. Informally some people use the expression for these steps: 1. Unlock the bolt and pull it back, ejecting any round or spent cartridge present in the breech. 2. Insert a round or allow one to feed from a magazine 3. Push forward and lock the bolt. I was trained on the British No.4 Lee-Enfield rifle, where the firing pin is cocked by the action of closing the bolt. Some other rifles, notably the Mauser 98k, cock the firing pin by opening the bolt. In all the bolt-action rifles I have used, **pulling** the bolt back opens the breech, ejecting any round present, and it is **pushing** the bolt forward which loads a round, whether the round was fed from a magazine or inserted by hand.

> cock verb
>   (PREPARE GUN)   [ T ]
>   to push the necessary piece of a gun up into position so that it is ready to fire:
>   *He cocked his rifle and took aim.*

[Cocking (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cocking)